# C# with NAV Dynamics web services inserting enum type object

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-dynamics

Let's say I've the web service for NAV dynamics

inside the web services there are some business objects which one of them is enum type

```
public Type Type {
            get {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
```

and has the value for the objects below, which contains in the web services too

```
public enum Type{

        /// <remarks/>
        _blank_,

        /// <remarks/>
        G_L_Account,

        /// <remarks/>
        Item,

        /// <remarks/>
        Fixed_Asset,

        /// <remarks/>
        Charge_Item,
    }
```

the case is when doing this method below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using NAVDomain;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using LocalDomain;
using NAVFacade.GoodReturnNAVService;

public bool SaveData(PurchCrdMemoNav objHd, List<Purch_Cr_Memo_Line> objDt)
            {
                PurchCrdMemoNav_Service service = new PurchCrdMemoNav_Service();
                NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();
                try
                {
                    cred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NAVUser3"];
                    cred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NAVPassword3"];
                    cred.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NAVDataSource3"];

                    service.Credentials = cred;

                    PurchCrdMemoNav DataSave = new PurchCrdMemoNav();
                    DataSave.No = objHd.No;

                    service.Create(ref DataSave);

                    var purch = service.Read(objHd.No);

                    DataSave.Buy_from_Vendor_No = objHd.Buy_from_Vendor_No;
                    DataSave.Buy_from_Vendor_Name = objHd.Buy_from_Vendor_Name;
                    DataSave.Applies_to_Doc_Type = objHd.Applies_to_Doc_Type;
                    DataSave.Applies_to_Doc_No = objHd.Applies_to_Doc_No;
                    DataSave.Location_Code = objHd.Location_Code;
                    DataSave.Posting_Date = objHd.Posting_Date;

                    DataSave.Key = purch.Key;

                    service.Update(ref DataSave);

                    DataSave.PurchLines = new Purch_Cr_Memo_Line[objHd.PurchLines.Count()];



                    for (int i = 0; i < objHd.PurchLines.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i] = new Purch_Cr_Memo_Line();
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].Document_Type = Document_Type.Credit_Memo;
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].Document_No = objHd.No;
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].Type = NAVFacade.GoodReturnNAVService.Type.Item;
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].No = objHd.PurchLines[i].No;  
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].Description = objHd.PurchLines[i].Description;
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].Unit_of_Measure = objHd.PurchLines[i].Unit_of_Measure;
                        DataSave.PurchLines[i].Quantity = objHd.PurchLines[i].Quantity;
                    }

                    service.Update(ref DataSave);

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MsgCode = 99;
                    MsgDesc = err.Message;
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

the problem is when executing the `service.Update(ref DataSave)` after the loop
its catching an error which said

**The field No. of table Purchase Line contains a value (C125) that cannot be found in the related table (Standard Text).**

because in NAV, when saving this one transaction, it needs to check it's item type each that recorded in this object below

```
DataSave.PurchLines[i].Type = NAVFacade.GoodReturnNAVService.Type.Item;
```

I've done the debugging and inside the DataSave.PurchLines[i].Type, there's the data that has the value as Item

but when i check the database, the data aint saved

> in NAV the object read as option, in SQL the object read as integer

please help,

I'm kind of stuck here
since anything on my code is working except this method

sincerely,

just another mediocore junior developer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your value isn't sent correctly, check if there is attribute "YourField"_Specified and set it to true...

EX:
...

```
    currWorkOrder.Order_Type = Order_Type.AKC; //(Order_Type)2;
    currWorkOrder.Order_TypeSpecified = true;
```

...
When i don't set

```
    Order_TypeSpecified = true;
```

plugin sends default value, so 0...

Answer (score 0):

yes, the Type field in NAV is an Option field but it's stored as Integer therefore you need to give it a numeric value.
Check with a NAV Developer of the actual database but the default values are:
" ,G/L Account,Item,,Fixed Asset,Charge (Item)" - it starts from 0 so if you want Item you'll need 2

I hope it helps!

Cheers

Comment: may i ask how, i'm literally newbs scrub here,
i change the container into business objects to integer
and giving another catch about the column (x, y) type data bla bla

Comment: you can't send int via Visual studi generated proxy, because that field is enum...